# Scoped CSS in Vue losing scope when using ExtractTextPlugin

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-component

Example Vue code (working in development):

```
<template lang="pug">
  .wrapper
</template>

<style lang="stylus" scoped>
  .wrapper
    min-height: 100vh
    display: flex
    justify-content: center
    align-items: center
    flex-wrap: wrap
    text-align: center
</style>
```

In development this works exactly as expected; only `.wrapper` within this particular template gets the styling applied to it thanks to the `data-v-XXX` attributes.

In production with extract text plugin however the styling is generated unscoped. It comes through identically sans the crucial `data-v-XXX` attributes.

My `webpack.production.config.js`:

```
'use strict'

const webpack = require('webpack')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer')
const rupture = require('rupture')

if (!process.env.NODE_ENV) process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './app/src/client.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/app/static/dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.pug', '.styl']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      DEVMODE: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css'),
    // This is until these loaders are updated for the new config system
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        // Enables this workaround setup to work
        context: __dirname,
        // Actual options
        postcss: () => [
          autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 3 versions', 'ie >= 9']
          })
        ],
        stylus: {
          use: [rupture()]
        }
      }
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            css: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
              loader: 'css',
              fallbackLoader: 'vue-style'
            }),
            stylus: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
              loader: [
                'css?-autoprefixer', // Disable css-loader's internal autoprefixer
                'csso',
                'postcss',
                'stylus'
              ],
              fallbackLoader: 'vue-style'
            })
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        loader: 'pug'
      },
      {
        test: /\.styl$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          loader: [
            'css?-autoprefixer', // Disable css-loader's internal autoprefixer
            'csso',
            'postcss',
            'stylus'
          ],
          fallbackLoader: 'style'
        })
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My development config is practically identical bar extract text plugin.

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you would benefit from opening a bug instead.

Comment: That was my thinking, so I've created a bare repo to reproduce the bug and... it's not there. So this will be a fun afternoon of debugging!

Comment: There ya have it :).  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that having dynamic requires in a `routes.js` that's being loaded by `vue-router` is a big no-no.

Changed this:

```
const view = fileName => require(`./components/pages/${fileName}`)

export default [
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: {
      name: 'intro'
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/intro',
    name: 'intro',
    component: view('Intro')
  },
  {
    path: '/form',
    name: 'form',
    component: view('Form')
  },
  // Backup catch-all route 404
  {
    path: '*',
    component: view('404')
  }
]
```

To this:

```
export default [
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: {
      name: 'intro'
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/intro',
    name: 'intro',
    component: require('./components/pages/Intro')
  },
  {
    path: '/form',
    name: 'form',
    component: require('./components/pages/Form')
  },
  // Backup catch-all route 404
  {
    path: '*',
    component: require('./components/pages/404')
  }
]
```

I suppose this makes sense as I believe Webpack statically analyses the requires for context.

Comment: Though the require-generator+string seems to output a definite require statement to us, the `view` function evals at run time, so before that, at compile time, webpack wouldn't know its result.